# Prob. 4, Chap. 6, in Baby Rudin: If $f(x)=0$ for all irrational $x$ and $f(x)=1$ for all rational $x$, then $f$ is not integrable on $[a, b]$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, proof-verification, definite-integrals

Here is Prob. 4, Chap. 6, in the book *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* by Walter Rudin, 3rd edition:

> If $f(x) = 0$ for all irrational $x$, $f(x) = 1$ for all rational $x$, prove that $f \not\in \mathscr{R}$ on $[a, b]$ for any $a < b$.

My Attempt:

> By Theorem 1.20 (b) in Baby Rudin, 3rd edition, between any two real numbers, there is at least one (in fact, infinitely many) rational numbers. From this we can also prove that between any two real numbers, there is at least one (in fact infinitely many) irrational numbers. Thus between any two real numbers, there are infinitely many rational numbers and infinitely many irrational numbers.
>
> Now let $P = \left\{ \ x_0, x_1, \ldots, x_n \ \right\}$ be an arbitrary  partition of the interval $[a, b]$, where 
>   $$ a = x_0 < x_1 < \cdots < x_n = b. $$
>
> Now for each $i = 1, \ldots, n$, there are infinitely many rational numbers and infinitely many irrational numbers in the sub-interval  $\left[ x_{i-1}, x_i \right]$; so we must have 
>   $$ \sup \left\{ \ f(x) \ \colon \ x_{i-1} \leq x \leq x_i \ \right\} = 1, $$
>   and 
>   $$ \inf \left\{ \ f(x) \ \colon \ x_{i-1} \leq x \leq x_i \ \right\} = 0.  $$
>   Therefore, 
>   $$ 
> \begin{align}
> U (P, f) &= \sum_{i=1}^n \sup \left\{ \ f(x) \ \colon \ x_{i-1} \leq x \leq x_i \ \right\} \cdot \left( x_i - x_{i-1} \right) \\ 
> &= \sum_{i=1}^n 1 \cdot \left( x_i - x_{i-1} \right) \\ 
> &= x_n - x_0 \\
> &= b-a, 
> \end{align}
> $$
>   and 
>   $$ 
> \begin{align}
> L (P, f) &= \sum_{i=1}^n \inf \left\{ \ f(x) \ \colon \ x_{i-1} \leq x \leq x_i \ \right\} \cdot \left( x_i - x_{i-1} \right) \\ 
> &= \sum_{i=1}^n 0 \cdot \left( x_i - x_{i-1} \right) \\ 
> &= 0.
> \end{align}
> $$
>   So if $\varepsilon$ be any real number such that $0 < \varepsilon < b-a$, then we see that 
>   $$ U(P, f) - L(P, f) = b-a > \varepsilon $$
>   for any partition $P$ of the interval $[a, b]$.
>
> Therefore (by Theorem 6.6 in Baby Rudin, 3rd edition) we can conclude that 
>   $f \not\in \mathscr{R}$ on $[a, b]$.

Is my proof good enough logic, rigor, and presentation-wise?

Comment: Yes it's good enough.

Comment: Straightforward!

Comment: Absolutely Perfectamente.